# How to get a list of Group Policy Objects applied to local workstation

Tags: c++, c, winapi, active-directory, gpo

My Windows service application runs on workstations belonging to the Active Directory domain. Once in a while I get user questions about some features of my program not working. Upon further investigation it usually turns out that certain *Group Policy Object* (GPO) settings are to blame.

So I was thinking, is there a way to list all GPOs applied to a local/member workstation? (I can then store them in the log file and quickly refer to it later if the problem comes up.)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, that "group policy" is just a good name... it consists of many individual registry entries... the only way to see this is to dump all these indivudual registry entries...

A starting point might be:

- [Group Policy Registry Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx)
- [Group Policy Registry Key Entries for Windows 7/Vista/XP and Server](http://www.mydigitallife.info/group-policy-registry-key-entries-for-windows-7vistaxp-and-server/)

Alternatively you can use the GPO API (which might be a better starting point):

- [GetAppliedGPOList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373518)

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. I looked at the GetAppliedGPOList() API and there two questions: 1. What am I supposed to use for the `pGuidExtension` parameter? and 2. What is the difference between that API and GetGPOList? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373520

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by simple windows command "gpresult".
Just open console and type `gpresult /r /scope computer` and you can get your result.

Comment: ERROR: Invalid syntax